# Heroku build failed after npm version update

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

So My previous builds were working just fine then I saw a warning in my terminal specifying the npm version I'm using is different than the npm version mentioned in my package.json so I updated my npm version in the package.json file and after then the Heroku build started to fail. So I dig some digging and found out on a related post that If I delete my package-lock.json file. It should do the work. So, I did the same and It worked. But I wanna know why it is not working with package-lock file. I tried again by doing npm install which created the package-lock file again but this time also the build failed. So Is there any way to build with package-lock.json Here's the build log ?

````
-----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  14.17.0
       engines.npm (package.json):   7.8.0
       
       Resolving node version 14.17.0...
       Downloading and installing node 14.17.0...
       Bootstrapping npm 7.8.0 (replacing 6.14.13)...
       npm 7.8.0 installed
       
-----> Restoring cache
       Cached directories were not restored due to a change in version of node, npm, yarn or stack
       Module installation may take longer for this build
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! code 1
       npm ERR! path /tmp/build_417a83d9/node_modules/bcrypt
       npm ERR! command failed
       npm ERR! command sh -c node-gyp rebuild
       npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
       npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
       npm ERR! gyp info using node@14.17.0 | linux | x64
       npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.6.9 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
       npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.17.0/node-v14.17.0-headers.tar.gz
       npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.17.0/node-v14.17.0-headers.tar.gz
       npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.17.0/SHASUMS256.txt
       npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v14.17.0/SHASUMS256.txt
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/tmp/build_417a83d9/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/tmp/build_417a83d9/node_modules/bcrypt/build/config.gypi',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/tmp/build_417a83d9/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/app/.cache/node-gyp/14.17.0/include/node/common.gypi',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/app/.cache/node-gyp/14.17.0',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/tmp/build_417a83d9/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/app/.cache/node-gyp/14.17.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/tmp/build_417a83d9/node_modules/bcrypt',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
       npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
       npm ERR! gyp: Undefined variable module_name in binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/tmp/build_417a83d9/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:376:20)
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:277:12)
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1088-aws
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_417a83d9/.heroku/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_417a83d9/.heroku/node/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_417a83d9/node_modules/bcrypt
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.0
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
       npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
       npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.ng4R4/_logs/2021-05-20T12_41_05_572Z-debug.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed ```
````

Comment: Locally and on deployment you are installing different library versions. The .lock file you generate locally is not compatible with the deployment. The reason why you are installing different library versions is either due to cache. In that case clear it (see https://help.heroku.com/18PI5RSY/how-do-i-clear-the-build-cache) or it is due to using different npm, node versions.

Comment: @TinNguyen It is happening because of different npm version only because I recently updated npm on my local machine. I cleared the cache but that too didn't work. I have removed the engines specified in my package file that seems to work for now.